# size of a binary tree using recursion

Tags: recursion, binary-tree

Can anybody explain exactly how this recursion works?
We calculate the size of the left sub tree and the right sub tree, but what about the nodes that are on the right side (i.e, right child) of the left sub tree? Also, why do we add the 1 everytime we call it?

```
int size(struct node* node) // We pass root 
{
   if (node==NULL) 
      return 0;
   else    
      return(size(node->left) + 1 + size(node->right));  
}
```

Comment: You should run through an example (perhaps with a pen and paper) to see how this works.

Comment: I did but i don't get it does it cal the left sub tree and right sub tree simultaneously? Say we don't have a right child of the parent node then does it return 0 for size(node->right) in the 1st step and for all the remaining step does it continue returning zero? Now say in the left sub tree i have 1 node which has two children then how do we calculate the right child?

Comment: Run it and find out ;)

Comment: I recommend running through an example using a table to keep track of variables in each call, as shown here: https://youtu.be/C128SsWVLkc?t=3m36s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how the recursion works.

```
int size(struct node* node) // We pass root 
{
if (node==NULL) 
return 0; //if the current node is null return a 0 so no add 1 is done
else    
return(size(node->left) + 1 + size(node->right));  
}
```

lets split up the return statement

return

size(node->left) recursive call to the left node of the current node

+1 for the current node

size(node->right) recursive call to the right node of the current node

by the time the recursion is done it will return the current size of the whole tree

if we start at the head of the tree it will call the left sub tree recursively until it hits a null, returns 0 for that node so no add 1 is done for it, then goes back up 1 level calls the right sub tree of last node not null and keeps going until the whole tree is done, adding 1 for each and only each node that is not null.

example

```
        5

    3       8

1      4 7     9
```

is the tree

the recursion starts at 5

it has both a left and right subtree

the left is called first 3
three has a left and right subtree
left first
so it goes to 1.
1 has no subtree but 1 is not null so it calls the left subtree which returns 0

0 + 1 + 0  is the 1 node return which is 1.

it then goes back up to 3

3 has a right subtree so it calls that

4 has no subtree so again its return will be 0 + 1 + 0

now back to 3
its return will be 1 + 1 + 1

now back to 5 so the return from the 3 node will be 3

so right now in the recursion it will be 3 + 1 + size->right

it will recursively return the right subtree so the return will be

3 + 1 + 3  which is 7 nodes not null

Answer (score 0):

Every binary tree has a root.  The root can be null, in which case this tree is empty and has size 0. Otherwise, there's at least one vertex (the root) plus however many vertices are contained in any subtrees hanging from the root.  This leads to two scenarios for calculating the size:

- If the root vertex is null, then the size of this tree is zero, end of story.
- If it's not null then the root vertex is the parent of two subtrees, a left subtree and a right subtree.  Regardless of whether the subtrees are empty or not, the total size of the tree will be `[the size of the left subtree] + [the size of the right subtree] + 1 (for the root vertex itself)`.

You need to recognize at this point that a subtree *is itself a tree*. You also will need to take the "recursive leap of faith" that `size()` **is** a function that returns the size of a tree, without worrying about how it manages to do so. If you can accept that as a fact, it should suddenly become obvious that the second case outlined above can be calculated by invoking the `size()` function on the left subtree, invoking it on the right subtree, summing the results, and adding 1 for the current (sub)tree's root! For both left and right, if there is no subtree the returned contribution will be zero.  Otherwise, trust the function to hand back the size of that subtree and use the results to calculate the current (sub)tree's size which you, in turn, hand back to whoever invoked you via the `return` statement.